# Button changes cell detail label

Tags: ios, uitableview

Setup: i have a view controller with a tableview inside it. I also have a button in the view controller. What I want to do is when I click the button, it should change the detail label text. What i having going now is my button action, and then my cellForRowAtIndexPath. Essentially i need to tell me cell that when my button is click to change the detail text with whatever information i want. I'm stuck with this...I can assign the button to change any label...but i can't figure out how to change the detail label with the button click. Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically set the content of a uitableviewcell (which includes textLabel.text and detailTextLabel.text) in cellForRowAtIndexPath method using a datasource. This datasource could be any model object derived by NSObject or it could be NSDictionary. When you process the button tap in button's action method, just update your datasource object for the row/section with the desired detailTextLabel text and call [tableView reloadData] to reload your tableview.